# Three different sets of points on the same plot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, distribution

I have created three sets of points by multivariate normal distibution:

```
library('MASS')
library('ggplot2')
library('reshape2')
library("ClusterR")
library("cluster")
mu1<-c(1,1)
mu2<-c(1,-9)
mu3<-c(-7,-2)
mu1
mu2
mu3
sigma1<-matrix(c(1,1,1,2), nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)
sigma2<-matrix(c(1,-1,-1,2), nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)
sigma3<-matrix(c(2,0.5,0.5,0.3), nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)
sigma1
sigma2
sigma3
simulation1<-mvrnorm(100,mu1,sigma1)
simulation1
simulation2<-mvrnorm(100,mu2,sigma2)
simulation2
simulation3<-mvrnorm(100,mu3,sigma3)
simulation3
X<-rbind(simulation1,simulation2,simulation3)
colnames(X)<-c("x","y")
X<-data.frame(X)
X
```

I need to represent these sets on one plot with different colours. Here I will attach image how it should be look like:
[Graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H819y.png)
Can somebody help me, how I can do this? I knew that graphic on image is created by ggplot, but I don'tknow exactly how to use it to my sets.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add some indicator to dataframe `X`  will make that plot

```
X$group <- rep(c("1","2","3"), each = 100)
X %>%
  ggplot(aes(x,y, group = group, color = group)) +
  geom_point() + xlab("aaaa") + ylab("bbbb")
```

[image]